# Wordpress theme - display posts marked as 2 categories

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I've been tasked with making a Wordpress theme, and there is 1 issue I just can't seem to find good information on.  I want to display posts on a page, but only if the post matches 2 categories (not either or, it has to be both or nothing is displayed).

So I tried a few things.  This was the best result:

```
<?php if(is_page("16")) {
      query_posts( 'cat=3&&cat=8' );
 } ?>
```

But this is an either or answer so both categories show up. I'm more comfortable in C#, so the syntax I'm looking for the wordpress equivalent for would be:

```
//Forgive the out of context syntax here
if(postCategory == "3" && postCategory == "8") 

//rather than
if(postCategory == "3" || postCategory =="8")
```

Basically if the post is tagged as both categories, it shows up.  Otherwise it does not.  I realize this is probably a noob question and maybe it has been answered somewhere, but over 2 hours of Googling and RTM have not produced anything.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it figure that once you post a question, you mysteriously come across the answer.

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

it was on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).  Guess I just skimmed over it.